# Compilation error Spark 1.3.1

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I tried to compile Spark 1.3.1 using the following flags
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4  -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 \
           -Dscala-2.11 \
           -Phive -Phive-0.13.1 -Phive-thriftserver \
           -DskipTests clean package
The compilation failed with the following the error.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Spark Project Parent POM ........................... SUCCESS       [01:08 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Core ................................. SUCCESS [02:38 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Bagel ................................ SUCCES  [ 17.700 s]
[INFO] Spark Project GraphX ............................... SUCCESS [ 35.732 s]
[INFO] Spark Project ML Library ........................... SUCCESS [01:11 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Tools ................................ SUCCESS [  6.718 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Networking ........................... SUCCESS [  6.837 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Shuffle Streaming Service ............ SUCCESS [  3.534 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Streaming ............................ SUCCESS [ 43.771 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Catalyst ............................. SUCCESS [ 48.411 s]
[INFO] Spark Project SQL .................................. SUCCESS [ 56.046 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Hive ................................. SUCCESS `enter code here`[01:01 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Assembly ............................. FAILURE [  6.365 s]
[INFO] Spark Project External Twitter ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume Sink .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External MQTT ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External ZeroMQ ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project REPL ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project YARN ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project YARN Shuffle Service ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Hive Thrift Server ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 09:45 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-15T11:25:53-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 77M/1176M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spark-assembly_2.10: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.spark:spark-assembly_2.10:pom:1.3.1: Could not find artifact org.apache.spark:spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11:jar:1.3.1 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project spark-assembly_2.10: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.spark:spark-assembly_2.10:pom:1.3.1: Could not find artifact org.apache.spark:spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11:jar:1.3.1 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Answer (score 0):

Seems no dependency of spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11 exists In maven repository, I also search it manually in maven repo and find nothing.  I think thrift server is not ready for scala2.11 for now.

Comment: Thank you! I switched to maven 2.10.5 and the compilation went smoothly.